# Symfony2 projet not working in prod with JSMserializerbundle and DoctrineMongoDBBundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

My symfony2 projet works flawlessly in the dev environment. The problem occurs when I switch to the production environment. When I call a controller which have an array of entities and serialize it to json with the JSMserializer, it crashes. The client still receive a response but the json is empty, not even a "[]". When I take a look in the logs I can read these errors:

```
    security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
    request.INFO: Matched route "employe_index" (parameters: "_controller": "Pisteur\WebRefugeManager\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller\EmployeController::indexAction", "_route": "employe_index") [] []
    request.CRITICAL: Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@proxy" in method Doctrine\MongoDB\Cursor::current() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? (uncaught exception) at /home/wpdemo/symfony/vendor/doctrine-common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php line 52 [] []
```

I've searched the errors in google and I found these two topics:

[https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/255](http://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/255)
https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/51

These topics didn't help me and I really dont understand the problem. Anyone has an idea?

**[EDIT]**
Here is my configs:

DEV:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:   { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml" }
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        firephp:
            type:  firephp
            level: info

assetic:
    use_controller: true
```

PROD:

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
```

[EDIT]

This is the commands I run:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console cache:warmup
php app/console assets:install web
php app/console assetic:dump web --env=prod --no-debug
```

Comment: what config differences do you have between the two environments ? Have you enabled a specific metadata cache driver ?

Comment: did u try clear your app/cache ?

Comment: Looks to me like a php sessions problem and not a symfony problem.  Are you sure sessions are set up the same in each environment?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue once, when deploying the first time with Capifony. I was only able to solve it by manually clearing app/cache/prod folder. Not using cache:clear, but actually removing the folder,

```
rm -rf app/cache/prod
```

I have yet to find out why `cache:clear --env=prod` sometimes wont clear it correctly, it may be a permission issue.